# iphone mail won't load google font Oswald

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, fonts

I've been digging into this issue for a while and have not found any solutions that work for me when trying to load up the Oswald front from Google on my iphone's mail app, it does load fine when I view the content FF, Safari, and Chrome. I haven't tried other google fonts so this could be an issue just with Oswald but really not sure why this isn't working.

Tried this option:
    
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald");

```
.Oswald{
    font-family:"Oswald";
}</style>
```

Then loaded up the class using class="Oswald"

And also tried this:
    link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

And then called the font up in the style font-family:Oswald;

Thanks to all for looking at this for me

Comment: Google Fonts should work fine on the iOS Mail App. 
it's best to use the link method instead of the import method, as most "modern" clients do not understand the import method.
Please try again with another font and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Funkysoulzh. I was able to use the Link method and then to get the iOS mail to pull in the font correctly I had to set up a CSS class and then call the class on each item within the html